# Error ./vpdetection: /gpfs/apps/x86_64-rhel5/matlab/R2012a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found

Tags: linux, matlab, g++, libstdc++

I am now trying to run some MATLAB code in Linux environment:

- Linux version is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga).
- gcc version is 4.1.2.
- MALTAB version is R2012b.

The statement in MALTAB that causes the problem is:

```
[status, result] = system('./vpdetection lines.tmp lines.out');
```

I got an error as follows:

> ./vpdetection: /gpfs/apps/x86_64-rhel5/matlab/R2012a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found

I have googled several solutions but they all require editing system files.
Since I am running the code on server where I don't have `sudo` right to edit system files.

Are there any other workarounds that don't need to edit system files?

---

I have tried `ldd` command. The result is as follows:

```
[sxh415@cyberstar vpdetection]$ ldd matlab/vpdetection
matlab/vpdetection: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by matlab/vpdetection)
matlab/vpdetection: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by matlab/vpdetection)
matlab/vpdetection: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.11' not found (required by matlab/vpdetection)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff7ff8000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003845400000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003840400000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003844c00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003840000000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000383fc00000)
```

Answer (score 0):

> /gpfs/apps/x86_64-rhel5/matlab/R2012a/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found

This error means: `libstdc++.so.6` distributed with your version of Matlab is too old, and does not provide version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14'. The matlab version corresponds to gcc-4.5 or earlier, but you have *some* code that was compiled with gcc-4.6 (or later).

You *must* arrange for your executable to pick up a newer libstdc++.so.6.

> I don't have sudo right to edit system files.

You could copy a sufficiently new version of `libstdc++.so.6` to `~/lib64`, then
 `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib64`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I downloaded a libstdc++6_4.8.1-9_amd64.deb and unpacked it. I got two files: libstdc++.so.6 and libstdc++.so.6.0.18. I copied them into ~/lib64 as you told me. There was no folder named "lib64", so I made one. I don't know whether it is ok to do that. Then I typed the command "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib64".

Answer (score 0):

Run `ldd` on your executable both inside MATLAB and outside on the system shell:

#### Shell

```
$ ldd ./vpdetection
```

#### MATLAB

```
>> !ldd ./vpdetection
```

To solve any dependency conflicts, try using `LD_PRELOAD` when launching either MATLAB itself or the executable:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libstdc++.so matlab
```

or

```
>> system('LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libstdc++.so ./vpdetection lines.tmp lines.out')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! As I mentioned before, I downloaded a newer version of libstdc++.so.6.0.18. But when I typed the command "LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/libstdc++.so.6.0.18 matlab", it shows: "/bin/bash: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /gpfs/home/sxh415/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.18)". Does it mean my version of libc.so.6 is too old and I need to find a newer version of libc.so.6 again?

Comment: I solved the problem. Thank you so much! I just found the code required gcc 4.4.3 version so I point LD_PRELOAD to libstdc++.so.6 from the 4.4.3 version of gcc. Thanks a lot for your help!