# How to update Matlab shared libraries?

Tags: linux, matlab, shared-libraries, conflicting-libraries

It appears that Matlab has its [own version](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/matlab#Blank.2Fgrey_UI_when_using_DWM.2FAwesome) of the linux shared libraries. I have a program that requires [libwfdb](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/binaries/linux/), a shared library that calls into a few of the standard shared libraries. The programs work fine on my machine, but when Matlab tries to call them using the `system()` function it fails because its versions are too old. Specifically, I get

`/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/glnxa64/libcurl.so.4: no version information available (required by /usr/local/lib64/libwfdb.so.10)`

Is there a way for me to update my Matlab shared libraries? Or is there a workaround where I can run the command as a local user? I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 if it matters.

EDIT: I'd prefer not to `link` all the libraries. I already tried that with `libcurl` and it failed because it wanted a new version of `libssl` and `libcrypto`.

Comment: perhaps use `LD_PRELOAD`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18563732/97160

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I was able to workaround this by setting my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in Matlab before running any of my system commands. Definitely not the best solution, but it works:

`setenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH', '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/');`